# swift downloading url and populating uiimageview

Tags: ios, swift, image, parsing, uiimageview

I'm having difficulty getting each image of my tableviewcell to show the thumbnail of my blog. the link is valid as i had it print to screen to make sure it works here is the block of code causing my brain aneurysm

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    let blogPost: BlogPost = blogPosts[indexPath.row]
    //cell.textLabel?.text = blogPost.postTitle
    postImageLink = blogPost.postImageLink
    cell.textLabel?.text = blogPost.postImageLink

    if postImageLink != "" && cell.imageView?.image != nil {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

            cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:self.postImageLink)!)!)
        }
    } else {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_0079")
        }



    return cell
}
```

i set the text label to postimagelink only to ensure it was parsing the correct code for future usage.
To be clear the problem is the thumbnails of my blog won't load. Only the preset image incase a thumbnail isn't present..postImageLink is a unique url for each thumbnail that I parsed.
(yeah i know i can write a parser but can't solve this problem =(..)
any help is appreciated before I throw my laptop off the roof thanks!
[here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8hAZ.png)

-rookieprogrammer

Comment: Please note that you cannot edit a view element (in this case `imageView`) outside the main queue.

Comment: Does that mean I am unable to download an image url into a UIImageView in the if statement? the compiler reads "nil" every time. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: No, it means you have to go back to main queue and do it there.

Answer (score 0):

try to make two blocks instead, to retrieve and set the image

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

    // retrieve image from url
    let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:self.postImageLink)!)!)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { Void in
        // set image in main thread
        cell.imageView?.image =  image
    })

}
```

can read more [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. It's just that should be doing it in the main_queue, UI main thread, to edit any UI objects.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      () -> Void in
  // retrieve image from url
  let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string:self.postImageLink)!)!)

  cell.imageView?.image =  image
}
```

Comment: when i get rid of the else statement the compiler finds my postImageLink "nil" every time. I can't figure out how to write the url to the postImageLink within the if statement.=/ any thoughts?